# Running ActiveRecord validations without saving

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a collection of ActiveRecord objects.  I want to be able to run all the validations for each of these objects without actually saving them to the database.  I just want to know if they would be valid were I to save them to the database. In other words, I essentially want to populate the `errors` data structure for each of my objects. Is there a way to do this?  Or perhaps I'm missing something about the lifecycle of the `errors` collection?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can do the following to check if a Model is valid:

```
@user = User.new
if @user.valid?
  #do things
```

If you want to see what the errors are, you can do:

```
@user = User.new
unless @user.valid?
  @user.errors.each {|k, v| puts "#{k.capitalize}: #{v}"}
```

Calling the ".valid?" method runs your validations, putting all of your errors into an ActiveRecord::Errors object, which can be accessed like I did in the example above.  Give the examples a try in the Console to get a feel for it if you like.

Comment: Along the similar lines, I am trying to display a publish link based on the record is valid for publish or not. In my validations, I am using  validates :if format. Is there any easy way to change the attribute to say :true and then check if it is valid for publish?

For e.g. 
post = Post.new(:title => "title", :published => false)
post.published = true
if post.valid?
post.published = false

Answer (score 4):

Running the `#valid?` method on the object will run all validations and populate the `errors` structure.

```
dude = Person.new
unless dude.valid?
  # Examine errors
end
```